# Wordpress Logout Redirect Follow up

Tags: redirect, logout

You answered a logout redirect question for this guy a while ago, I implemented the code and it worked great, thanks! (http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-logout-page-redirect-to-homepage)

My follow up question is how you would format that code to specify a unique URL if it wasn't the home page?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. What kind of landing page do you have in mind: post, page, archive, external webpage, ... ?

Comment: Who is "You"? Please read the [faq] to see what this site is about. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're addressing me ;-)

If you want to modify this code snippet:

```
add_action( 'wp_logout','go_home' );

function go_home(){
  wp_redirect( home_url() );
  exit();
}
```

you can replace the `home_url()` part with your custom page URL:

```
'http://example.com/landingpage/'
```

but I wouldn't recommend hardcoding the landing page, if it's an internal page.

You can try to construct the landing page with various WordPress functions:

You have for example [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) and extra input parameters to [`home_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url). Then there's [`get_category_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link), [`get_tag_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tag_link), [`get_post_type_archive_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_archive_link), ... etc.

If you explain what kind of landing page you have in mind (page, post, archive, custom, external) then I can expand it further.